# Bind value to object property, in an object, in an array, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, deep-linking, 2-way-object-databinding

Ok, heres the pickle:

Im using ng-repeat to iterate through the menu items:

```
<!-- start the list/loop -->
<ion-list ng-repeat="this in menuItems.items track by $index" type="item-text-wrap">

    <a class="item" ng-click="addToCart({{this}})">{{this.name}}
        <span class="badge badge-stable">{{theCart[$index].product.qty}}</span>
    </a>

</ion-list>
<!-- end the list/loop -->
```

The problem arises when I try to get the value out of the item in the cart 'theCart[$index].product.qty' since the $index is not bound to any particular item, just the position in the array. I need to get to a unique identifier 2 objects deep in the array so I can be sure to get the correct values with the two-way data binding Angular is so nice to provide.

```
theCart: [{
    product: {
        id: 1,
        section: 'sides',
        name: 'mayo',
        price: 7,
        outOfStock: '',
        qty: 1
    }
}, {
    product: {
        id: 0,
        section: 'sides',
        name: 'ranch',
        price: 6,
        outOfStock: '',
        qty: 1
    }
}];
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? "this.id" won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have understood your question properly.

But assuming that `menuItems.items` is an array of products that for some reason its items don't have the property `qty` and that `theCart` is a different array of products in which its items do have the property `qty`. And that what you want is to get the available quantity of the product that you are iterating from the array `theCart`, you could do it using the [filter 'filter'](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), like this:

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="item in menuItems.items" type="item-text-wrap">
    <a class="item" ng-click="addToCart(item.id)">{{item.name}}
        <span class="badge badge-stable">
           {{(theCart | filter:{product:{id:item.id} })[0].product.qty}}
        </span>
    </a>
</ion-list>
```

I must say that **this is a very ugly way to do it**, I wouldn't recommend doing it like this to anyone. **It would be much better to generate a "joined array" of those 2 arrays in the controller and to iterate that "joined array" instead**.

Comment: Thanks. I agree this looks pretty ugly. I think I will just refactor the array structure to be one 'menu[]' array with a 'cart:0' and 'cart:1' boolean property. This seems like it would be the Angular way since it will utilize the two-way data binding in its most distilled form. Minimum code to get the result. Agreed?